# Program gives error when for loop is commented

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have found a strange behaviour in my java program here is my code looks like this

```
public class JavaTest {

    private final int dataSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() * 0.6);

    public void test() {
        {
            System.out.println(dataSize);
            byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
        }

//      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//          System.out.println("Please be so kind and release memory");
//      }

        System.out.println(dataSize);
        byte[] data2 = new byte[dataSize];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaTest jmp = new JavaTest();
        jmp.test();
    }
}
```

Here when I am commenting the `for` loop I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` that i can understand the jvm heap sapce is full.

But *with that `for` loop in my code*, it executes properly. How comes?

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly? It is hard to read.

Comment: Read this newsletter from @HeinzKabutz http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue174.html

Comment: I am getting OutofMemoryError with out the loop and its executing when i am uncommenting the for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's because you declare `byte[] data` inside `{ }` block, which means `data`'s scope ends when the code block ends. With loop uncommented, you are probably giving time to garbage collector to free the memory taken by `data`. And when you comment out the loop, GC doesn't have time to free up that memory yet.

If you remove `{ }` around `data` declaration, it will also throw `OutOfMemoryException` even with loop uncommented.

**UPDATE**

[This blog post](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue174.html) stated in the comments by @SubOptimal proves this theory wrong, looks like it doesn't have anything to do with time needed by GC to free the memory. I'll quote relevant parts from the blog

> The majority of responses were incorrect and suggested that the for() loop either gave the GC time to do its work during the System.out.println()...
>
> Some of my readers realised that it had nothing to do with the System.out.println and that a simple int i = 0; would suffice. **If you declare any local variable immediately after the code block, you break the strong reference to the byte[] held in the stack frame** 1 before you invoke the new byte[] the second time.

Comment: same notice :) just came to post this, and found ur answer, looks logical to me too.

Comment: @Yazan :) Was strange at first, until I saw `{ }`, didn't notice it when I first read the question.

Comment: exactly until i copied code to eclipse , CTRL+SHIFT+F... and then HELLO THERE :)

Comment: According to the [blog post](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue174.html) linked by @SubOptimal in the comments, this is not correct. However, when I try, it gives OOME even for just one array, so I can't really test it...

Comment: @tobias_k You're right, I'll edit my answer with info from that blog post. Thanks.

Comment: though it's related to GC :) somehow ... ;)

Comment: @tobias you are right i have gone through that article but could not figure it ho it is happening can you put off your idea in a different answaer.

Comment: @PredragMaric do you mean its freeing the resources from stack when we are declaring a local variable.

Comment: @AbhijitChakra simply the print statement, or even int x=1, -as in the article- will make the first declaration of `data[]` more garbage-collectible... so GC cleans it Freeing memory

Comment: @AbhijitChakra I'm not that familiar with byte code but that's more or less how I understood it.